# Devexpress pivotgrid Customization CustomizationFormStyle

Tags: forms, grid, devexpress, pivot, customization

I show fields in customization form. I choose `Excel2007` as `CustomizationFormStyle` but I would like to show just `Filter` area. I want `Column`, `Row` and `Data` area to be invisible.
How can I manage this?

```cs
pivotGridControl1.OptionsCustomization.CustomizationFormStyle = DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.Customization.CustomizationFormStyle.Excel2007;
pivotGridControl1.OptionsCustomization.CustomizationFormLayout = CustomizationFormLayout.BottomPanelOnly1by4;
pivotGridControl1.OptionsCustomization.CustomizationFormAllowedLayouts = CustomizationFormAllowedLayouts.BottomPanelOnly1by4;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`PivotGridControl.ShowingCustomizationForm`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridControl_ShowingCustomizationFormtopic) event and [`PivotGridControl.ShowCustomizationForm`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridControl_ShowCustomizationFormtopic) event. In `PivotGridControl.ShowingCustomizationForm` event you need to get `CustomizationForm` object from [`CustomizationFormShowingEventArgs.CustomizationForm`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridCustomizationFormShowingEventArgs_CustomizationFormtopic) property and use this object in `PivotGridControl.ShowCustomizationForm` event to customize the customization form. To get the filter area and other area objects, you need to use `CustomizationForm.BottomPanel` property and its `GetAreaLabel`, `GetAreaIcon` and `GetAreaList` methods.
Here is example:

```cs
private void pivotGridControl1_ShowingCustomizationForm(object sender, CustomizationFormShowingEventArgs e)
{
    _customizationForm = e.CustomizationForm as CustomizationForm;
}

private void pivotGridControl1_ShowCustomizationForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    var bottomPanel = _customizationForm.BottomPanel as ExcelCustomizationFormBottomPanel;

    var areas = new PivotArea[] { PivotArea.ColumnArea, PivotArea.RowArea, PivotArea.DataArea };

    foreach (var area in areas)
    {
        bottomPanel.GetAreaLabel(area).Hide();
        bottomPanel.GetAreaIcon(area).Hide();
        bottomPanel.GetAreaList(area).Hide();
    }

    var filterAreaList = bottomPanel.GetAreaList(PivotArea.FilterArea);
    var dataAreaList = bottomPanel.GetAreaList(PivotArea.DataArea);
    filterAreaList.Height = dataAreaList.Bottom - filterAreaList.Top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem by your answer @nempobu4